# Command : exec echo "this is for test" > test ; how does shell arrange for output re-direction?

Tags: unix, exec

I am trying to understand how, for the above command, the shell arranges for output re-direction when the process associated with the shell itself is replaced by that of echo? Would very much appreciate any help.

Regards
Rupam

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually in my system, the echo is a separate program in /bin. So, when I invoke that program explicitly using :

exec /bin/echo "this is for test new" > test

it would force the shell process to be replaced by that of /bin/echo. But output re-direction works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Output redirection of an external command is achieved by manipulating file descriptor, typically involving `dup2`, a system call that assigns a file descriptor to an existing open file. In this case, the standard output of the process that executes `echo` is instructed to point to the target output file.

The shell does a close equivalent of the following steps:

1. create a copy of the current process by invoking [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html); the subsequent steps happen in the child process. (This step is omitted when the command is invoked with `exec`, as in your example.)
2. open `test` for writing and remember the file descriptor
3. make file descriptor 1 equal to the descriptor, by calling [`dup2(fd, 1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html)
4. call [`execlp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) or similar to replace current process execution with execution of `echo`

The `echo` command simply writes to standard output, a fancy name for file descriptor number 1. It doesn't care if that ends up writing to a TTY, to a file, or to another program. The above steps make sure that file descriptor 1 really points to the open file `test`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I understand the output re-direction part, but a confused about the fork() part (I am relatively new to Unix). Isn't it true that we invoke exec to avoid fork-ing of an extra process? So, where would the child be created from? Also, the session exists after execution of echo - as expected as there is not shell process to return to - but had there been a child process, then exit from echo (or the subshell executing it) should return to parent-shell (where I start my session from). And that's not the case.

Comment: @RupamBhattacharjee Step 1 (fork) is omitted for the command you gave, which begins with `exec`. This is stated in parentheses at the end of step 1.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Sorry about missing it at the first place.

Regards
Rupam